# Variance of Multi-Dimensional Ornstein Uhlenbeck process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to compute the asymptotic variance of OU process
$$
d X_t = - H X_t dt + S dW_t
$$
where $X_t$ takes value in $R^d$. $H$ and $S$ are $d\times d$ matrices that does not have $HS = SH$ in general. How to compute its variance at $t$?

Things are classical for one dimensional case as
$$
Var (X_t) = \sigma^2 / \mu (1-e^{-\mu t})
$$

Comment: Are $H$ and $S$ constants?  I haven't tried, but would expect most of the one-dimensional proofs to go through without trouble.  For instance, Mehler's formula is available in higher dimensions.

Comment: Also, what initial conditions do you have in mind for $X_0$?

Comment: Thanks. $H$ and $S$ are $d\times d$ matrices that does not have $HS = SH$ in general (I added that into my question). For initial vector it does not matter since the stationary distribution here is not dependent on $X_0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the large-$t$ limit $\rho$ of the variance of $X_t$ is given by

$$\rho=\int_0^\infty \exp(-tH)SS^{\dagger}\exp(-tH^{\dagger})dt$$

where the superscript $\dagger$ indicates the transpose (or the conjugate transpose if the matrix is complex); this result holds also if $S$ is $d\times d'$ with $d'\leq d$; see, for example, page 11 of these [notes](http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/goodman/teaching/MonteCarlo07/notes/sde2.pdf), which also show how to evaluate the integral by Schur decomposition of $H$.